# How to ignore empty Objects "{}" but not empty Strings in ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I need to serialize (ignoring empty objects ("{}")) non-structured object which can have any content.

From version 2.9.X FasterXML have changed logic of it work for (Include.NON_EMPTY).
In older version it had worked as I need.
But now it is ignoring empty strings too.

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
```

Lets suppose that we have next java object (for convenience it will look like a JSON):

```
{
    "mapA": {},
    "listA": ["",
        {
            "emptyString": "",
            "string": "some text"
        },
        {}
    ],
    "emptyString": "",
    "mapB": {
        "emptyString": "",
        "mapC": {}
    }
}
```

Converting it to JsonNode:

```
   mapper.convertValue(/*our Object*/, JsonNode.class);
```

Desired output(Again for convenience it will look like a JSON):

```
{
    "listA": ["",
        {
            "emptyString": "",
            "string": "some text"
        }
    ],
    "emptyString": "",
    "mapB": {
        "emptyString": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what you're starting from? If you start from Java, what's an empty object? I would have thought that a non null Java object with only null fields is never handled in a specific manner by Jackson. Maybe you could write a little filter that drops "empty objects" from the serialization result?

Comment: @JPMoresmau, empty Objects - its empty Map or any empty Collection

Comment: Ah OK, then the docs say it uses isEmpty() for collections and length()==0 for string, so there doesn't seem to be a way to ignore empty maps but not empty strings

Comment: @JPMoresmau, I figured out how to do this. If you are interested, you could check it =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used `Include.CUSTOM`:

```
    private static class ExludeEmptyObjects{
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof Map) {
                return ((Map) o).size() == 0;
            }
            if (o instanceof Collection) {
                return ((Collection) o).size() == 0;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
   mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(Value.construct(Include.NON_EMPTY, Include.CUSTOM, null, ExludeEmptyObjects.class));
```